# Whitespace at the right side of page and remains from positioning [css,html]

Tags: html, css, list, icons

i am new here and generally i recently started to learn webdev and i am trying to make little "portfolio" website to train practice skills. I have one problem what i can't solve, and i am siting with eyes on screen about few hourse what makes me so confused

1. First issue is whitespace on right side of the page.
   2.Next issue is a lot of whitespace what remaining after relative positioning.
   How can with these get rid of these things?

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="pl">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title></title>
   <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
   </head>
   <body>


   <!--header-->
   <header>

   </header>



   <div class = "container">

   <div class="text">
   <h1 id = "h1">“The life of a designer...” </h1>
   <h2 id = "h2">Is a life of fight. Fight against the ugliness. 
   Just like a doctor fights against disease. For us,
   the visual disease is what we have around, and what we 
   try to do is cure it somehow with design.</h2>
   <h3>– Massimo Vignelli. </h3></div></div> 

   <div class="txt">
   <p id ="one">Hi, i am webdeveloper<id></id></p>
   <p id ="two">If you want work with me</p> 
   <p id ="three">leave a message.</p>
   </div>


   <div class = "icons">
   <img src = "icons/cheap.png" alt = "cheap" id="cheap"/>
   <img src = "icons/Trust.png" alt = "trust" id="trust"/>
   <img src = "icons/timeliness.png" alt = "timeliness" id="timeliness"/>
   <img src ="icons/developing.png" alt ="developing" id="developing"/>
   </div>

   <div class = "Social">
   <a href=""><img src ="icons/facebook.png" alt ="fb" /></a> 
   <a href=""><img src ="icons/instagram.png" alt ="insta" /></a>  
   <a href=""><img src ="icons/linkedin.png" alt = "linkedin"/></a>   

   </div>






   <!--Overview-->  
   <section>
   <article>
   Aaaa
   </article>

   </section>


   <!-- Social media icons-->     
   <aside>
   </aside>  

   <footer>
   </footer>   
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
       @font-face {
       font-family: myFirstFont;
       src: url(/fonts/Graviola_Regular.otf);
       }

       @font-face {
       font-family: czcionka;
       src: url(/fonts/czcionka.ttf);
       }

       body {
       margin:0px;
       padding:0px;
       }
       header{
       background-image:url(bg1.jpg);
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       height:800px;
       opacity: 0.8; 
       background-size:100% 100%;





      }
      .txt {
      position:relative;
      right:-50px;
      top:-1120px;
      border-left:3px solid white;
      font-family:czcionka;



     }

     .txt #one {
     position:relative;
     color:white;
     font-size: 50px;
     position:relative;
     bottom:-60px

     }
     .txt #two {
     position:relative;
     color: white;
     font-size: 50px;


     }
     .txt #three {
     position:relative;
     color: white;
     font-size: 50px;
     top:-60px

     }

     .container .text {
     color:white;

     text-align: center;
     position:relative;
     top: -450px;
     margin: 50px;
     font-family: myFirstFont;



     }

     .container .text #h1 {
     font-size:60px;
     border-bottom: 3px solid;
     font-family:myFirstFont;
     }
     .container .text #h2 {
     font-size: 25px;
     font-style:italic;
     }
     .container .text #another {
     position: relative;
     top:-500px;
     font-family:myFirstFont;
     font-size:40px;

     }


    .Social {
    position: relative;
    top:-1460px;
    right:-50px;
    margin:500px;
    }
    .icons #cheap {
    position: relative;
    top:-1139px;
    right:-1225px

    }


   .icons #timeliness {
   position:relative;
   top:-1140px;
   right: -1110px


   }

   .icons #developing {
   position:relative;
   top:-1140px;
   right:-750px;


   }
   ```

[Here's link to img how this looks. When i scroll down page rest of my site elements are very far down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ECrg.jpg)

[Like this looks the white space what i talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stUf6.jpg)

Comment: Hi Marcin, welcome to SO. The first step you need to take in order to receive proper help here is to create a [mcve] of your problem. Edit your question and use the `<>` button, placing each piece in its place (`html`, `css` and `js`). If you need to, you can also link different resources using the tools on the left bar. After you create a verifiable example, people will be able to inspect it and provide the advice you need.

Comment: although it seems to get you most of the way there,  using position absolute can be an exercise in futility as you move toward building a responsive design. I recommend exploring some tutorials on [`flex-box`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you should read the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: Relative positioning is not the solution here as you have seen @MarcinJagiello. I like to think of relative positioning as acting like a projection. A relative positioned element continues to take up the space in the location it was originally placed and is only moved visually when using `right`, `bottom`, `left` and `top`. Make sure you know the difference and what happens when you use the `position`, `float` and `display` properties and their various values. It will take time to grok. [LearnLayout.com](http://learnlayout.com/) might be a place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've read about flexbox and it was a solution for my problem!